# How to give coordinates from variable

Tags: iphone

I have set of coordinates saved in array. I am using reverse geocoder

The method i used,

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate altitude:(CLLocationDistance)altitude horizontalAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)hAccuracy verticalAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)vAccuracy timestamp:(NSDate *)timestamp
```

I need to convert latitude,longitude in CLLocationCoordinate2D.

```
self.atmLocation.latitude = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"]; //atmlocation is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D.
```

This gives me an error "Expression is not assignable". How to solve this? And if this is not possible than please suggest any other way so i can use external set of coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tempDict returns an object. Hence you need to convert it.

Try `self.atmLocation.latitude = [(NSString *)[tempDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"]doublevalue];`

From the documentation

```
typedef struct {
   CLLocationDegrees latitude;
   CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;

typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

Comment: Paste the code where you are creating the atmLocation and tempDict.

Comment: You can also typecast the return from tempDict into NSString and then use the above method.

Comment: Type cast the value from [tempDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] into NSString. Check my edit